# How would I fit all elements into a Segmented Control?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I currently have 6 elements in my segmented control that I'd like to fit all on the screen at once but I can't find a way to do so.

I've looked for ways to change the Segment size based on the text and also tried to change the frame of each segment.

```swift
struct BundleView: View {

    let areas = ["Crafts Room", "Pantry", "Fish Tank", "Boiler Room", "Bulletin Board", "Vault"]

    @State var selectedArea = 0

    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $selectedArea, label: EmptyView()) {
            ForEach(0..<areas.count) { index in
                Text(self.areas[index]).tag(index)
            }
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

    }
}
```

[Current display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ePrX.png)

This is what it currently looks like in Portrait mode.  There is only 4 our of the 6 elements being shown.

Landscape mode will shows all of the segments which is what I want.

Comment: One option would be to put the segmented control into a scrollview.

Comment: You can try also changing the font size using `segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], for: .normal)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You can't fit all your text "as is" into a segmented picker, because the designers of SwiftUI didn't build segmented pickers to have that many options. You have a couple alternatives.

**Images**

As dasblinkenlight suggested, you can replace the text with small images, which should fit up to 6 choices:

```
struct BundleView: View {

    let areas = ["a.circle", "b.circle", "c.circle", "d.circle", "e.circle", "f.circle"]

    @State var selectedArea = 0

    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $selectedArea, label: EmptyView()) {
            ForEach(0..<areas.count) { index in
                Image(systemName: self.areas[index]).tag(index)
            }
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
    }
}
```

[image]

**Custom Control**

You can build a custom control. Here's a cool design with animation from [swiftui-lab.com](https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/):

[image: Custom Control]

**But why can't I use Picker?**

SwiftUI tends to have two types of Views:

1. Those designed to be easily modifiable and composable, providing unlimited customizability for a unique look and feel.
2. Those designed to provide a standard, consistent feel to some type of interaction, regardless of what app they are used in.

An example of type 1 would be Text. You can change font size, weight, typeface, color, background, padding, etc. It is designed for you to modify it.

An example of type 2 would be Picker. You are not in direct control of item width, you can't change the padding around views, you can't tell it wrap to multiple lines, etc. They don't want it to be very customizable, because then each app's pickers would behave differently, defeating the purpose of a standard control.

*Segmented Pickers work best with 2-4 items, whose descriptions are relatively short.* If you want something outside that, you need to make a custom control.

Comment: Thank you, I went with this approach in your animation.  I realize the limitations now

Comment: Have fun with Stardew Valley!

Answer (score 1):

One approach to squeeze more information onto the same screen space is using pictures instead of words:

- Make six icons corresponding to the locations in your segmented control (Crafts room, Pantry, etc.)
- Replace text-based segments with image-based ones,
- If necessary, add a read-only text above the segmented control to spell out the meaning of the currently selected icon.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution inspired by our friend @john-m is this:

```
struct SegmentedPickerStyleExample: View {
    
    var frequencyTypePart1 = [FrequencyType.perDay.name,
                              FrequencyType.perWeek.name,
                              FrequencyType.per2Week.name,]
    var frequencyTypePart2 = [FrequencyType.perMonth.name,
                              FrequencyType.per3Month.name,
                              FrequencyType.per6Month.name]
    
    @State private var selectedFrequencyType = FrequencyType.perDay.name
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center
        ) {
            
            Picker("Select a repetition format", selection: $selectedFrequencyType) {
                ForEach(frequencyTypePart1, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            Picker("", selection: $selectedFrequencyType) {
                ForEach(frequencyTypePart2, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        }
    }
}
```